# Force synchronous iframe load

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an iframe pointing to arbitrary foreign domain `http://A`. I want to send it to another foreign domain `http://B` on a user event.

Say `http://B` is slow to load. If I just set `iframe.src = "http://B"`, then the iframe will keep the contents from `A` until `B` is downloaded fully and can render. This is confusing for the user because they asked for `B`, but all they see is `A`.

I want to load a page from my domain, say `../html/loading.html`, in between `A` and `B`. Assume that this page load will always be fast.

I have observed that setting `iframe.src` is asynchronous. Consider the following code:

```
iframe.src = '../html/loading.html';
iframe.src = 'http://B';
```

This skips opening `../html/loading.html` and goes right to `http://B`. (Regardless of how fast `loading.html` might be, or how slow `B` might be). I also tried doing this:

```
iframe.src = '../html/loading.html';
iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
iframe.src = 'http://B';
```

However, this throws cross-domain errors, saying I can't access stuff in the `contentWindow` of `http://A` (because `loading.html` hasn't loaded, we're still on `http://A` and I can't force a reload).

Is there a way to force an iframe to do a synchronous load of a URL? I'm writing a Chrome Extension, so if it has to be specific to `crx` that's okay too.

Comment: You can do it by creating 2 `iframe`s. One for `loading`, one for `//B`. Show `//B` when it's done loading, then hide `loading`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Initially iframe should load loading.html using

```
    iframe.src = '../html/loading.html';
```

In client side onload event of loading.html, the source should be changed to other domain B using

```
    iframe.src = 'http://B';
```

Comment: Awesome. I think I will pass the URL to B as a parameter to loading; ie: `iframe.src = '../html/loading.html?next=B'`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to load the next URL as soon as the current URL is done loading, luckily for us the iframe has an onload event we can use.

You'll want to do something like this:

```
iframe.src='../html/loading.html'
//load the next page after finishing loading the last one
iframe.onload=function(){iframe.src='http://B';}
```